# I/O error while booting live usb - UPDATE

Tags: live-usb, 19.10

I honestly have no idea what's going on right now, I'd appreciate it if I had some help:

edit: I'm running windows off of a 1tb HDD and tried to install Ubuntu on a partition on said HDD. I've successfully done this with Linux Mint in the past. There is also a 1tb M.2 SSD with nothing on it installed on the motherboard... just to clarify.

I'm trying to boot up a live usb disk install of Ubuntu (19.10), but I keep running into this error: "Buffer I/O error on Logical Block 0, async page read"

I've researched this error and it seems to be caused by a damaged usb stick...
However, I've tried 5 different usb sticks at this point, even switched versions (20.04 to 19.10) and I'm still encountering this error.

I'm using balenaEtcher to flash the drives, and I've also tried Rufus to the same result.
I've ran chkdsk on windows to find all of the drives in question have come back with "no errors found"

update: I booted into the live usb environment successfully and began installation... ubiquity then proceeded to take 45 minutes to make it through all the menus, and it eventually finished. however, i was unsuccessful booting ubuntu. I managed to get the recovery utility to function but i was greeted by this:[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlWiX.jpg)

I then went under "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" in GRUB and chose Recovery Mode. fsck then spat out this error: [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQIJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this was caused by a malfunctioning USB floppy drive i was using. I dunno why it was doing this but unplugging it fixed the issue.